# DualShock 3 usability on PS4

Tags: ps3, controllers, ps4

Does anyone know if DualShock 3 controllers are usable for PS4? i.e. if the PS3 controllers are forward compatible.

KR,

Comment: There's really not a feasible way they could be with the way some games rely on the touchpad...

Answer (score 5):

Sorry but dual shock 3 is not compatible with the ps4, but the ps4 controller is some what compatible with the PS3.

Referenced from http://au.ign.com/wikis/playstation-4/PS4_Compatible_PS3_Devices